# Finding maximum of a function with unknown constants

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a function in the form:

$$y = \frac{ax}{b + \frac{x^2}{c} + x}$$

Supposedly, the maximum of this function is equal to $\sqrt{bc}$.

I've tried substituting in $\sqrt{bc}$ for $x$, but I don't really know what any of my answers mean in relation to the maximum value for $y$.

All of the constants are positive.

How can I prove that $\sqrt{bc}$ is the maximum? can I just take the derivative of the function and assume that terms without $x$ coefficients go to 0?

Comment: What do we know about (the signs of) the constants?

Comment: They are all positive. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Who the hell downvoted all of the answers (pardon my language)? Is there any way to flag users based on such rapid downvote usage? I'm going to upvote all answers to at least set the count back to $0$. Geez...

Comment: @induktio Thanks. Kestrel, could you clearify if it is OK to assume that $c<4b$ (see my answer below)? Otherwise your function will typically have singularities and no maximum.

Comment: @mickep Yes, it's safe to make that assumption. This equation actually describes an enzymatic assay; the unknown constants are either rate constants or compound concentrations in solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if $c\geq4b$ then the polynomial in denominator is zero at $x=\frac{1}{2}(-c\pm\sqrt{c^2-4bc})$. Thus, we assume that $c<4b$ (if this is not the OK, check the limits as $x$ approaches these zeros)

Since $y(x)\to0$ at $x\to\pm\infty$ and $y$ attains positive values and is differentiable it suffices to check points where $y'(x)=0$.

We have
$$
y'(x)=\frac{ac(bc-x^2)}{(bc+x(c+x))^2}
$$
so $y'(x)=0$ only for $x=\pm \sqrt{bc}$. Now
$$
y(\sqrt{bc})-y(-\sqrt{bc})=\frac{4a\sqrt{bc}}{4b-c}>0
$$
since $4b>c$. Thus the maximal value is attained at $x=\sqrt{bc}$.

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to second derivative test, to confirm that you, in fact, have a maximum, or you'll need to show that the functions behavior changes from increasing to decreasing at the critical point.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The terms $a,b$ and $c$ are constants. Using the quotient rule: $$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}(x) = \frac{a\left(b+\frac{x^2}{c}+x\right) - ax\left(\frac{2x}{c}+1\right)}{\left(b+\frac{x^2}{c}+x\right)^2}.$$

Check (or solve for it, whatever) that $\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}(\sqrt{bc}) = 0$ and that $\frac{{\rm d}^2y}{{\rm d}x^2}(\sqrt{bc}) < 0$. You will compute $\frac{{\rm d}^2y}{{\rm d}x^2}$ in the same fashion as $\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}$.

Comment: As in, $\frac{{\rm d}^2y}{{\rm d}x^2}$ will be the derivative of $\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}$?

Comment: Exactly! $\frac{{\rm d}^2y}{{\rm d}x^2} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\left(\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see what I get. This could get nasty.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of $y$ as $x$ approaches $\pm\infty$ is zero, so if there is only one critical point and $y$ is positive there it must be a maximum. If, as in this case, there are two critical points, and $y$ is positive at only one of them, that one must be a maximum.

Comment: Byt $y'=0$ at $x=\pm\sqrt{bc}$.